# Ubuntu 19.04; no automatic graphical login screen shown on boot

Tags: boot, login, login-screen

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.04. Since then, when I boot up my machine I get a screen showing the boot log, but not then switching to the login screen.

I can manually start the login screen by pressing [CTRL][ALT][F2] followed by [CTRL][ALT][F1].

How can I get the login screen to appear automatically?

The boot log (from /var/log/boot.log, but matching what I see during boot) is:

```
[  OK  ] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Started Discard unused blocks once a week.
[  OK  ] Started CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Started Trigger anacron every hour.
[  OK  ] Listening on Activation socket for spice guest agent daemon.
         Starting Socket activation for snappy daemon.
[  OK  ] Listening on ACPID Listen Socket.
[  OK  ] Started Daily rotation of log files.
[  OK  ] Started Daily man-db regeneration.
[  OK  ] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
[  OK  ] Started ACPI Events Check.
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
[  OK  ] Started Message of the Day.
[  OK  ] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[  OK  ] Listening on CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Started Daily apt download activities.
[  OK  ] Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
[  OK  ] Reached target Timers.
[  OK  ] Listening on Socket activation for snappy daemon.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
         Starting Accounts Service...
         Starting LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
         Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
[  OK  ] Started ACPI event daemon.
         Starting Disk Manager...
[  OK  ] Started irqbalance daemon.
         Starting Switcheroo Control Proxy service...
         Starting Bluetooth service...
         Starting Rotate log files...
         Starting Login Service...
[  OK  ] Started Run anacron jobs.
         Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...
         Starting Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd...
[  OK  ] Reached target Login Prompts.
[  OK  ] Started Save initial kernel messages after boot.
         Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...
[  OK  ] Reached target Sound Card.
         Starting System Logging Service...
         Starting Modem Manager...
         Starting Daily man-db regeneration...
[  OK  ] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
         Starting Network Manager...
         Starting WPA supplicant...
[  OK  ] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
         Starting Configure Plugged-In Printer...
         Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
[  OK  ] Started CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Reached target Printer.
         Starting Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down...
[  OK  ] Started Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor.
         Starting Snappy daemon...
[  OK  ] Started Switcheroo Control Proxy service.
[  OK  ] Started Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down.
[  OK  ] Started Login Service.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[  OK  ] Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
[  OK  ] Started Bluetooth service.
[  OK  ] Started WPA supplicant.
[  OK  ] Started Thermal Daemon Service.
[  OK  ] Started System Logging Service.
[  OK  ] Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
[  OK  ] Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
         Starting Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
[  OK  ] Reached target Bluetooth.
         Starting Authorization Manager...
[  OK  ] Started Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.
         Starting Hostname Service...
[  OK  ] Started Authorization Manager.
[  OK  ] Started Hostname Service.
[  OK  ] Started Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager.
         Starting Network Manager Wait Online...
[  OK  ] Reached target Network.
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
         Starting OpenVPN service...
[  OK  ] Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Started OpenVPN service.
         Stopping CUPS Scheduler...
[  OK  ] Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Started CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Started Permit User Sessions.
         Starting GNOME Display Manager...
         Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
         Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
[  OK  ] Started Modem Manager.
[  OK  ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
```